# freachable queue and finalization queue

Tags: .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, garbage

What is difference between freachable queue and finalization queue?
One Solution:[Transition from Finalization Queue to FReachable Queue .net Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705236/transition-from-finalization-queue-to-freachable-queue-net-garbage-collection)

Answer (score 16):

Both queues are for the purpose of managing finalizable objects.

Reference : [What do you know about Freachable queue?](https://nabacg.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/what-do-you-know-about-freachable-queue/)

> Freachable what? You might ask. Freachable (pronounced F-reachable) is
>   one of CLR Garbage Collector internal structures that is used in a
>   finalization part of garbage collection. You might have heard about
>   the Finalization queue where every object that needs finalization
>   lands initially. This is determined based on whether he has a Finalize
>   method, or it’s object type contains a Finalize method definition to
>   speak more precisely. This seems like a good idea, GC wants to keep
>   track of all objects that he needs to call Finalize on, so that when
>   he collects he can find them easily. Why would he need another
>   collection then?
>
> Well apparently what GC does when he finds a garbage object that is on
>   Finalizable queue, is a bit more complicated than you might expect. GC
>   doesn’t call the Finalize method directly, instead removes object
>   reference from Finalizable queue and puts it on a (wait for it.. )
>   Freachable queue. Weird, huh? Well it turns out there is a specialized
>   CLR thread that is only responsible for monitoring the Freachable
>   queue and when GC adds new items there, he kicks in, takes objects one
>   by one and calls it’s Finalize method. One important point about it is
>   that you shouldn’t rely on Finalize method being called by the same
>   thread as rest of you app, don’t count on Thread Local Storage etc.
>
> But what interest me more is why? Well the article doesn’t give an
>   answer to that, but there are two things that come to my mind. First
>   is performance, you obviously want the garbage collection to be as
>   fast as possible and a great deal of work was put into making it so.
>   It seems only natural to keep side tasks like finalization handled by
>   a background thread, so that main one can be as fast a possible.
>   Second, but not less important is that Finalize is after all a client
>   code from the GC perspective, CLR can’t really trust your dear reader
>   implementation. Maybe your Finalize will throw exception or will go
>   into infinite loop? It’s not something you want to be a part of GC
>   process, it’s much less dangerous if it can only affect a background
>   thread.