# What is the purpose of Freachable queue

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, finalizer, finalize, finalization

I am going through .net basics, and i am not able to understand why does .net need freachable queue why can't the finalization stuff happen in the finalization queue.

Any help to help me understand this would be deeply appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: This question answers you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206532/freachable-queue-and-finalization-queue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [freachable queue and finalization queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206532/freachable-queue-and-finalization-queue)